# How can I configure facebook plugin for vuejs with slots

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, facebook-login

I need to integrate facebook plugin into my vuejs application. I wanted to use
vue-facebook-login-component plugin but I am confused at some points. I can not change text, it doesnt have a text prop, instead it has a text slot. And their slot example doesnt have a api-id which needed for facebook login.

They have to slot example but I could not understand how to use it, never used slot before. I searched google but still can not make it.

When I used in my code, slot-scope="scope" gives scope is defined but never used error, so my first question is how will I use it ?

Another issues is, in slot example  it doesnt have app-id, I confused where to put id when I use slot, and how to get login-logout information.

this one works but I can not change login/logoutworking texts.

```html
<v-facebook-login app-id="966242223397117"></v-facebook-login>
```

this is the example with slot given on the plugin page

```html
<template>
  <v-facebook-login-scope>
    <button slot-scope="scope">
      <!-- Compose HTML/CSS here, otherwise nothing will be rendered! -->
    </button>
  </v-facebook-login-scope>
</template>
```

and this is my original button code where I want to integare facebook login. How will I use his code in above code-with-slot ? and where will I put app-id ? Here it is a more detailed code with slot from the plugin and it doesnt have api-id either.

https://github.com/adi518/vue-facebook-login-component/blob/master/src/components/FBLogin.vue

```html
    <v-button
      class="gray fw shadow-none login-box__submit"
      title="FACEBOOK İLE GİRİŞ YAP"
    />
```

so what I tried is directly putting my button inside of it (just giving class doesnt work)

This brings button with my button class but stays connecting and never bring login

```html
<template>
  <v-facebook-login-scope>
    <button slot-scope="scope">
      <!-- Compose HTML/CSS here, otherwise nothing will be rendered! -->
    <v-button
      class="gray fw shadow-none login-box__submit"
      title="FACEBOOK İLE GİRİŞ YAP"
    />
    </button>
  </v-facebook-login-scope>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<v-facebook-login app-id="966242223397117">
<span slot="login">FACEBOOK İLE GİRİŞ YAP</span>
</v-facebook-login>
```